# Nativescript / Android: avdmanager shows devices but nativescript can't find them

Tags: android, android-emulator, nativescript, android-virtual-device, nativescript-vue

To install android virtual devices on linux I have follow this instruction https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/android-virtual-devices

I have installed everything, downloaded and created an AVD. So when I run `./avdmanager list` I get a bunch of devices listed, e.g.

```
id: 1 or "android-28"
     Name: Android API 28
     Type: Platform
     API level: 28
     Revision: 6
```

But when I run `tns device` it can't find anything:

```
Connected devices & emulators
Searching for devices...
Cannot find connected devices.
```

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install Android Studio then use it to create devices it'll definitely work.

Please notice that in this case you will have to change the SDK root paths as described in the same docs you read already; that's because Android studio will install the require libraries in a different location.